# ElectronJS on RaspberryPi3B - Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: touchscreen, gui, raspbian-buster, raspbian-lite

I am trying to develop an ElectronJS GUI application on the RaspberryPi3B with the standard 7" touchscreen connected. Currently, I have 
Raspbian Buster Lite and I use SSH to connect to the Pi. I tried to start the electron application using `npm start` (`electron .`), but I receive the following error: `(electron:30597): Gtk-WARNING **: 03:14:44.077: cannot open display:`. How do I resolve this? Is there a better development & deployment workflow for doing this?

Comment: How did you expect to display GUI on Raspbian Lite?

Comment: I just don't have a desktop. But, I have installed all the chrome libraries and the 7" display is working and displaying default terminal items like `Under-voltage detected!` warning.